# phpsessid - Is it worth changing the session name to something hashed and visitor specific

Tags: php, security, session-cookies, sessionid

I'm wondering whether for security purposes it would be worth using the session_name() function to rename the default phpsessid to a hashed or encrypted id?

If so, what would be the best way to implement it??

Thanks,

Comment: I would recommend reading http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot written about this on the web, and previous questions I've read on StackExchange. Encrypting your session_id just creates another random number that is as easy to hijack as the original random number.

If you think about it, if you encrypt a session you will either reassign session_id to the new number (in which case you have achieved nothing) or you will use encryption / decryption functions in your script.

If you use the latter method, and someone get's hold of another users encrypted Session ID, it will be decrypted by your script and access will still be granted.

In short, there is very little point and no real utility in further encrypting your session_id above and beyond the random number it is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Rename **PHPSESSID**  to another name, say **MYNEWNAME**, because anybody with little idea about **PHP** knows that **HTTP** server doesn’t maintain state and can only keep track of users using **PHPSESSID**.
The PHPSESSID is stored in the clients cookie so I don't consider it as secure. Someone might bruteforce it and perform some action (like a Facebook status post) whenever a session was successfully hijacked. Read more on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75310/protect-from-people-bruteforcing-the-phpsessid